# Reordering Angular JS array items breaking on first item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I assume I have a syntax error here.

I have a group of 4 functions in my controller: add new item, delete current item, move item backward (up) in the array, move item forward (down) in the array.

They all are working *except* when the item to be moved down is the first object

```
vm.maxChoices = 6;

vm.addNewChoice = function(arr) {
  var newItemNo = arr.length + 1;
  arr.push({
    'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
  });
};

vm.deleteChoice = function(arr, index) {
  arr.splice(index, index);
};

vm.moveUpChoice = function(arr, index) {
  var currItem = index;
  if (currItem>0) {
    arr.splice(currItem-1,0, arr.splice(currItem, currItem)[0]);
  }
};

vm.moveDownChoice = function(arr, index) {
  var currItem = index;
  var newPosition = index+1;
  if (currItem < arr.length) {
    arr.splice(newPosition,0, arr.splice(currItem, currItem)[0]);
  }
};

vm.showAddChoice = function(choice,arr) {
  return arr.length !== vm.maxChoices;
};
```

What did I do wrong with moveDownChoice?

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WPdnmYbDSXC0LsbeMduM?p=preview

Try creating 3 or 4 rows, put data in the fields to see it move.  You can move #2 to #3 etc., but if you try to move the first one down, it creates a NEW item instead of moving to #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for both `moveUpChoice` and `moveDownChoice` are incorrect.  Neither functions the way you expect.

The `.splice()` function has 3 parameters.  `position`, `numToRemove`, and `itemsToInsert`.  it returns an array of the items removed.

so in your code, you are telling it to go to the item's position, remove the item's position number of items, then pass the first of those to be added at the new position.  In the first row, you'll remove 0 items (0 based arrays), but in other rows, you will be removing more data than you actually add to the new location.  The up arrow will have the next to the last item disappear from the array.

Instead, try `arr.splice(newPosition,0, arr.splice(currItem, 1)[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

In both your moveUpChoice and moveDownChoice function you've got the same bug.

```
arr.splice(currItem, currItem)[0]
```

should be:

```
arr.splice(currItem, 1)[0]
```